# How to get the latest image from the AZ ACR show-tags list

Tags: bash, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I have command like below

```
TEST=$(az acr repository show-tags -n AAAA --repository AAAA --orderby time_desc --top 10 | jq ".[] | select(test(\"^AAA.0\"))")
```

command returning multiple values like

```
- "AAA.1"
- "AAA.2"
- "AAA.3"
```

how to get latest i.e. AAA from the output

Comment: What `$TEST[0]` returns for you?

Comment: Post adding brackets around the whole command like ($(az acr repository show-tags -n AAAA --repository AAAA --orderby time_desc --top 10 | jq ".[] | select(test("^AAA.0"))"))
i am able to read it like ${TEST[0]}

Answer (score 1):

The below should return the latest value:

```
echo  "AAA.1" "AAA.2" "AAA.3"| awk '{print $(NF)}'
```

The output:

```
AAA.3
```

from awk man page:

> The variable NF is set to the total number of fields in the input record.